# Insertion sort animation jquery

Tags: jquery, insertion-sort

I wanna animate insertion sort with divs but it only changes 2 divs' places and after this animation stops.Animation workes fine with one for loop.So is it because of for loop or did i make mistake?

```
  <body>
  <button onclick="func1()">Click</button>
</body>

<script>
  var arr = [4, 7, 1, 9, 8, 13, 6, 11];

  function showarray() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      var divSort = document.createElement("div");
      divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
      divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
      divSort.style.background = "yellow";
      divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
      divSort.style.margin = "10px";
      divSort.id = arr[i];
      divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
      document.body.appendChild(divSort); }}

  showarray();

  function func1(){

    for (var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        var index = arr[i]; 
              var j = i;
      while (j > 0 && arr[j-1] > index){
       arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            j--;}
         doSetTime(i,j);} }


   function doSetTime(i,j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + arr[j]).insertBefore("#" + arr[i]);
    }, i * 1000);}
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide working code snippet.

Comment: @dummy What is expected result of `while (j > 0 && arr[j-1] > index)` ?

Comment: @guest271314 if our element smaller than elements before it then this puts element its right place

Comment: @dummy If call `console.log(arr[j], arr[j - 1])` after `arr[j] = arr[j-1]` appear setting same value for `arr[j - 1]` as `arr[j]` ? Is this expected assignment ?

Comment: What is expected resulting order of `div` elements ? Not entirely certain , here , if all `div` elements position should be changed or "sorted" ?

Comment: @guest271314 div elements should be sorted

Comment: @dummy _"div elements should be sorted "_ According to their `id` , or `.innerHTML` ? 1 - 13 ?

Comment: @guest271314 according their id

Answer (score 1):

> div elements should be sorted
>
> according their id

Try using `Array.prototype.slice()` to create copy of `arr` array , `Math.min()` to sort copied array from minimum value to maximum value , `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove appended item from copied array , `.appendTo()`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <button onclick="func1()">Click</button>
</body>

<script>
  var arr = [4, 7, 1, 9, 8, 13, 6, 11];

  function showarray() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      var divSort = document.createElement("div");
      divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
      divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
      divSort.style.background = "yellow";
      divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
      divSort.style.margin = "10px";
      divSort.id = arr[i];
      divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
      document.body.appendChild(divSort);
    }
  }

  showarray();

  var copy = arr.slice();

  function func1() {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, copy);
    doSetTime(min);
    copy.splice(copy.indexOf(min), 1);
  }

  function doSetTime(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + i).appendTo("body");
      if (copy.length) {
        func1()
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

Alternatively , create a container element to append elements to

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <button onclick="func1()">Click</button>
</body>
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
  var arr = [4, 7, 1, 9, 8, 13, 6, 11];

  function showarray() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      var divSort = document.createElement("div");
      divSort.style.width = 30 + "px";
      divSort.style.height = 30 + "px";
      divSort.style.background = "yellow";
      divSort.style.display = "inline-block";
      divSort.style.margin = "10px";
      divSort.id = arr[i];
      divSort.innerHTML = arr[i];
      document.body.appendChild(divSort);
    }
  }

  showarray();

  var copy = arr.slice();

  function func1() {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, copy);
    doSetTime(min);
    copy.splice(copy.indexOf(min), 1);
  }

  function doSetTime(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + i).appendTo("#container");
      if (copy.length) {
        func1()
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Is there any way i can do it with selection,bubble or insertion sort?

Comment: @dummy _" Is there any way i can do it with selection,bubble or insertion sort? "_ What are "selection" ?, "bubble" ? , "insertion sort" ?

Comment: it's sorting algorithm. basically i need to show how algorithm works with animation

Comment: What would be animation ? Could substitute complete callback of a jQuery animation for `setTimeout`

Comment: animation should do the same thing you code do but not with Array.prototype.slice() with any ready algorithm

Comment: _"but not with Array.prototype.slice() with any ready algorithm"_ ? Not certain interpret this portion of comment correctly ? What type of animation ? `.fadeIn()` , `.fadeOut()` ? What `css` property of appended element should be animated ?

Comment: no only with insertbefore() function actually what you did look like insertion algorithm but you did it without its code :)